# Programatically changing theme in a Jquery Mobile component

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Why theme 'e' is not reflecting in the output?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <title>title</title>

        <script>
            $(document).bind('pageinit', function() {
                $('input').attr('data-theme', 'e');
            });
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <input type="text" />

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$( "#input" ).textinput({ theme: "e" });`

Comment: The above code works when initialising a input, but after its created into DOM, the best way is adding/removing classes.

Comment: This is what exactly in the Jquery document. But it is not working! Have you tested yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is no direct and easy way to do this.

Omar presented a working solution, but it depends on the way JQM render components. This might not work for a future version of JQM if they change their rendering model.

Why can't we think of replacing the component itself? (something like following)

```
$('selector').html('<input type="text" data-theme="e"/>').trigger('create');
```

This method may be a little odd if your component has many attributes, but it seems reliable and applicable to any JQM components that you like to change dynamically.

Answer (score 3):

Since `.textinput` doesn't work with `refresh` nor `create`, here is a simple way to do it.

```
$('input').closest('div').removeClass('ui-body-c');
$('input').closest('div').addClass('ui-body-e');
```

The default theme for input is `c`, so you remove it from the parent div and add theme `e`. However, `textinput` will still have `ui-body-c` class but `ui-body-e` will override it when it's added to the parent div.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/2RkRK/)**

Answer (score 0):

You may have to trigger a refresh.

```
$('input').attr('data-theme', 'e').trigger('refresh');
```

Comment: You tested it or writing by theory?:-) It is not working for me!

Comment: Just writing by theory, also looking it up :). You tried anything with the `.buttonMarkup()` function?